# Facebook Login Issue with WebView not Closing using (Swift 3.0 FacebookLogin 0.2.0)

Tags: ios, facebook, swift3, facebook-ios-sdk

The pods I'm using from my podfile:
PODS:
  - Bolts (1.8.4):
    - Bolts/AppLinks (= 1.8.4)
    - Bolts/Tasks (= 1.8.4)
  - Bolts/AppLinks (1.8.4):
    - Bolts/Tasks
  - Bolts/Tasks (1.8.4)
  - FacebookCore (0.2.0):
    - Bolts (~> 1.8)
    - FBSDKCoreKit (~> 4.15)
  - FacebookLogin (0.2.0):
    - Bolts (~> 1.8)
    - FacebookCore (~> 0.2)
    - FBSDKCoreKit (~> 4.15)
    - FBSDKLoginKit (~> 4.15)
  - FBSDKCoreKit (4.16.0):
    - Bolts (~> 1.7)
  - FBSDKLoginKit (4.16.1):
    - FBSDKCoreKit

My LoginViewController.swift code:

```
import FacebookLogin
class LoginViewController: UIViewController, LoginButtonDelegate {
/*!
 @abstract Sent to the delegate when the button was used to login.
 @param loginButton the sender
 @param result The results of the login
 @param error The error (if any) from the login
 */


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let loginButton = LoginButton(readPermissions: [ .publicProfile ])
    loginButton.center = view.center
    loginButton.delegate = self;
    view.addSubview(loginButton)

}

/**
 Called when the button was used to login and the process finished.

 - parameter loginButton: Button that was used to login.
 - parameter result:      The result of the login.
 */
public func loginButtonDidCompleteLogin(_ loginButton: FacebookLogin.LoginButton, result: FacebookLogin.LoginResult){
    print("hello!")
}

/**
 Called when the button was used to logout.

 - parameter loginButton: Button that was used to logout.
 */
public func loginButtonDidLogOut(_ loginButton: FacebookLogin.LoginButton){
    print("goodbye")
}
```

My modified AppDelegate.swift Code:

```
public func application(_ application: UIApplication,  didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey : Any]? = nil) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    return SDKApplicationDelegate.shared.application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
}

func application(_ application: UIApplication, open url: URL, sourceApplication: String?, annotation: Any) -> Bool {
    return SDKApplicationDelegate.shared.application(application, open: url, options: [:])
}
```

**Context:**
I downloaded everything with pods, and was prompted by xcode to convert all code to swift 3.0 so I did so. I followed this guide for getting started and logging in: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/swift
If I run without the second function in my app delegate, I am forced to press "done" from the web view that pops up after logging in, then I get a response "hello" and if I set a breakpoint at that point I see that my login was perceived as canceled. In addition, the facebook button I initialized still prompts me to log in so it definitely did not work. In addition I also get this error:

> -canOpenURL: failed for URL: "fbauth2:/" - error: "The operation couldn’t be completed. (OSStatus error -10814.)"

HOWEVER, if I leave that method in, it closes but the delegate never gets called. Also the button proceeds to prompt me to log in.

My Info.plist:

```
<key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
            <array>
                <string>fbMYID</string>
            </array>
        </dict>
    </array>
    <key>FacebookAppID</key>
    <string>MYID</string>
    <key>FacebookDisplayName</key>
    <string>MYAPPNAME</string>
    <key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
    <array>
        <string>fbapi</string>
        <string>fb-messenger-api</string>
        <string>fbauth2</string>
        <string>fbshareextension</string>
    </array>
```

**Extra Information:**
I'm new to swift but I can tell that I need the method I took out to allow it to work but am unsure of how to approach this. I don't have anything called FBSDKApplicationDelegate (viewed from other questions similar that I've browsed) since I'm using the new swift SDK from here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/swift. I'm guessing that doc for login is outdated given the current version of swift or I missed a link pointing to some pre-requisite. Please let me know if you have any idea of the solution to my issue. My info.plist should be all set or else I would have errors attempting to log in. I am able to reach the screen where it says You have already granted *MYAPP* permission. Then I proceed to press ok, then if I had the openURL method in my app delegate it closes, or it stays blank. I STRONGLY SUSPECT it has to do with the options that I left with a blank dict from the open method when calling the SDKApplicationDelegate.  Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the problem was with my keychain sharing. As soon as I went to mytarget > capabilities > Keychain sharing and then enabled it, it worked.

Answer (score 0):

First create app from developer.facebook.com and add you appID also in plist

than add one button to your storyboard and add this code to your app for login

```
 let loginManager = LoginManager()
    loginManager.logIn([.publicProfile], viewController: self) { loginResult in
        switch loginResult
        {
        case .failed(let error):
            print(error)
        case .cancelled:
            print("User cancelled login.")

        case .success(let grantedPermissions, let declinedPermissions, let accessToken):
            print("granted \(grantedPermissions.contains("email"))")
            print("Logged in user! \(loginResult)")
            print("accesstoken - \(accessToken)")
            print("user ID - \(accessToken.userId)")
           }
           }
```

add facebook through Pod file that helps alot

Comment: check my updated question, I added part of my plist. Do you mean like that? It was already like that.

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood, but I still face an exception with this solution. If I make your changes to the first appID then I get an exception, if I add fbauth2 to both facebook app id's then I get another exception, if I make it to the last ID alone I get a exception.

Comment: Through facebook what you really want to do like facebook login & logout ? thing or ? what you really want to do tell me?

Comment: Sorry for super late reply but I want to be able to do facebook login and logout.

Comment: my login button worked fine and my plist was fine, it was my keychain sharing.